# Using wildcard to open multiple csv files Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I say I have a few tables with the same headers stored in multiple .csv files

I want to do something like this

```
scala> val files =  sqlContext.read
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header","true")
.load("file:///PATH_TO_FILE/*.csv")
```

But when I do this I get extra columns from the headers of the other files

In a simple case I have 2  .csv files, when I load them seperately and then combine them using unionAll I get the right number of lines. But When I try to do the above to load them, I get an extra line (coming from the header line of the second file). Loading them seperately and then unionAll them won't work since there may be a lot of files I need to open.

Is there anyway to do the above so that the extra headers aren't included

Answer (score 0):

You might ultimately have to join all of them. To have it done at once, you can try something like below.

```
//Get all the individual file paths
def getListOfFiles(dir: File):List[File] = dir.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).toList
val filelist = getListOfFiles(new File("file:///PATH_TO_FILE/"))

//Read from the list of files you created
val Files= filelist.map(file => { sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").load(file.getPath.toString) })

//Merge all the data into a single rdd
val mergedFile= Files.reduce((x, y) => x.unionAll(y))
```